# Where to code the placement and configuration of subviews in a UIView belonging to a UIViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiviewcontroller

It just occurred to me that I may not be doing this right.  I've been told a couple of times that the `viewDidLoad` method  is called upon the first reference to `self.view`. Therefore, the following code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
if (self) {

    self.view.frame = frame;

    }
    return self;
}
```

has the frame assignment done after `viewDidLoad` is executed.

Therefore, any reference to self.view.frame inside `viewDidLoad` is not going to refer to the correct frame.

More importantly, if I am using autoresizingMask (struts and springs) for the subviews inside the main view (self.view), any proportional spacing is going to be based on the wrong initial proportions. The documentation on autoresizingMask states:

> When more than one option along the same axis is set, the default behavior is to distribute the size difference proportionally among the flexible portions.

What is the right way to configure the view of a UIViewController? Is it as simple as configuring and adding subviews in the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods?

Comment: alternatively you could subclass the UIView and use layoutSubviews.

Comment: If I create an initWitFrame method for my subclassed UIViewController, is there a "built-in" way that the view of that controller is initialized with that frame? I don't think so, but just how is the view frame initialized? Right now, I saved frame from the method call in an ivar and set the view frame from that inside viewDidLoad. I think this is getting a little sloppy.

Comment: according to your custom `initWithFrame:` method your are initializing the view controller and then setting the frame of the view(which doesnt point to any particular view at that point) before assigning the view of the viewcontroller. So you should set the view first and then set the frame.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask its `view` to a `UIViewController`, if the view has not been instantiated yet (it is the first time you ask it), it needs to be created (°).

When a ViewController needs to instantiate its view:

- If a XIB is associated with your `UIViewController`, then the view is loaded from the XIB. This means that the XIB file is unarchived, and all the objects described in the XIB are allocated / instantiated. Each view in the XIB is thus instantiated using `alloc`+`initWithCoder:`+`autorelease` (the `NSCoder` being the decoder that unarchive the XIB). Each of your views will thus receive the `initWithCoder:` message
- If there is no XIB associated with your `UIViewController`, it will call its `loadView` method to allow you to create the view programmatically. In this case, you write code in there to create your views, like `[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...] autorelease]`. Thus your views will be instantiated by code and receive the `initWithFrame:` message, not the `initWithCoder:` method.
- One the `UIViewController` view has been created and instantiated either by unarchiving the XIB file or by code in `loadView`, the view is loaded and the `UIViewController` receive the `viewDidLoad` message.

So each view receive either the `initWithFrame:` (if created by code) or `initWithCoder:` (if created from a XIB) message first, and then once all the view hierarchy of the `UIViewController`'s `view` is created, the `UIViewController` itself receive the `viewDidLoad` message. That's always in that order.

---

```
@implementation YourCustonUIView
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder
{
  // here the view is being allocated from the XIB. "alloc" as been called, "initWithCoder" is in progress
  // frame is not set at this line, but as soon as we call the super implementation…
  self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
  if (self)
  {
    // Here all the properties of the view set in the XIB file (thru the inspector) are now applied
    // Including the frame of the view (and its backgroundColor and all what you set thru IB)
    // so self.frame is initialized with the correct value here
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  // here the view is being allocated from code. "alloc" as been called, "initWithFrame" is in progress
  // self.frame is not set at this line, but as soon as we call the super implementation…
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self)
  {
    // Here the view is initialized with its frame property
    // so self.frame is initialized with the correct value here
    // and you can initialize every other property from here
  }
  return self;
}
@end

@implementation YourCustomUIViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  // At that point, the view of your UIViewController has been loaded/created
  // (either via XIB or via the loadView method), so either its initWithCoder (if via XIB)
  // or its initWithFrame (if via loadView) has been called
  // so in either case, its frame has the right value
}

/*
// In case your YourCustomUIViewController does not have a XIB associated with it
// You have to implement this method to provide a view to your UIViewController by code
-(void)loadView
{
  // Create a view by code, and give it a frame
  UIView* rootView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,..., ...)];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // for example
  self.view = rootView;
  [rootView release];

  // at the end of this method, self.view must be non-nil of course.
}
*/
@end
```

---

*(°) Another possibility is that the view has been instanciated but later on deallocated, because you received a memory warning while your view was not on screen so the memory used by the view has been reclaimed. But in any case, the view is thus not yet loaded and has to be loaded/created*

Comment: Since I am working from a subclassed UIViewController, I'm not sure how to get to where its view is initialized. There is no [super initWithFrame...]. It's not part of the class.

Comment: Of course there isn't. Did you see my code snippets? `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:` are methods of `UIView`, not `UIViewController`. (In fact `initWithFrame` is a method of `UIView` and `initWithCoder:` in a method of the `NSCoder` protocol, to which `UIView` conforms to). That's why I put these methods in `@implementation YourCustonUIView` in my example. Read what I explained in my answer again: the `initWithFrame:` or `initWithCoder:` method are called on your `UIView` instances, whereas `viewDidLoad` method is called on your `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't scroll down, I guess. (Still getting used to the inverted scrolling with the new OS.)